# Error with Docker Compose Django and PostgreSql

Tags: python, django, docker

I have a problem when I create any object in my django admin. It shows me this error:

```
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "license_portal_client" WHERE
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'
    
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python license_portal/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

My database `settings.py` and I have added my app on installed apps:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

And here is my `models.py`:

```py
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

And my `admin.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from license_portal.models import Person

admin.site.register(Person)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to your database not being migrated. Try running the django migrate command **from within a django container** and stop any existing database connections you may have -- like the `web` container running the development server.

```sh
# Stop all of the running containers to release all db connections
docker-compose stop

# Run the migrate command inside of the django container
docker-compose run web python license_portal/manage.py migrate

# Start all of the containers again to access your dev server
docker-compose up web
```